# Animated setView() in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a search bar in my leaflet map and I would like the map to slowly zoom and pan to the marker when selected from the search bar. I can get it to zoom and pan but not slowly. My desired effect would be similar to when you type in a location in Google Earth and the view 'flys' from one location to the next. This is the code I have which zooms to my location but not slowly.

```
controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({layer:listOfMarkers, propertyName: 'IntersectionName', circleLocation:true,  position:'topleft'});
    map.addControl(controlSearch)

controlSearch.on('search_locationfound', function(e){
    map.setView(e.latlng,15, {animate:true, duration:10.0})
});
```

I'm using leaflet v0.7.7.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change the duration of any `setView` that changes the current zoom level in Leaflet 0.7.7*. The duration of any animated zoom is hard-coded to be 0.25s, and because `setView` accepts [zoom/pan options](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoompanoptions), which do not include `duration`, your `duration:10.0` will be ignored.

However, `setView` does accept separate options for panning and zooming, and because the [pan options](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-panoptions) do include duration, you can pan smoothly *at the current zoom level* using the following:

```js
map.setView(e.latlng, map.getZoom(), {
  "animate": true,
  "pan": {
    "duration": 10
  }
});
```

I realize that this is not quite what you are looking for, but it is one step closer.

*In Leaflet 1.0b, there is a [`flyTo` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-flyto), which produces the effect you describe, but there is nothing similar in 0.7.7.

Comment: `react-leaflet` version 4 is out (by now) and it is possible to set duration in `setView` function. `map.setView([latitude, longitude], undefined, {animate: true,duration: number});`

Answer (score 5):

Another way

```
map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom(), {
      animate: true,
      duration: 0.5
    });
```